# SignalR - message sending timings and load

Tags: c#, typescript, signalr

Im working on my master thisis and I have a quick question about "SignalR" message send/receive times in fast intervals.
Im testing how SignalR is behaves when sending N number of messages with S [kB] size every I time interval ... (message is processed for 500ms in HUB - simple SLEEP), and results are not looking too prommising... they are weird.
Should it look like this?

With 100 messages each with size of 740kB sent one by one every 1000ms chart looks like (fine by me):
[image]

BUT for 100 messagess with size of 1240kB sent one by one every 500ms chart looks like...
[image]

in sample off 1000 messages - 740kB - 500ms:
[image]

sometimes this... stairway to heaven starts in middle of test and Im curious why its there

Comment: looks like reached certain limit, i.e. memory, hard drive speed, etc. the processing is cached, thus slows down. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Is this for SignalR .NET Core or SignalR ASP.NET?  How many servers do you have?  Is there a backplane?

Comment: It is .Net Core, 1 server and only for SignalR HUB (Angular is in seperate project) and I have not configure anything besides routing and CORS